# OpenCV-3.1.0のVisual Studio2015での環境構築の際に、"cannnot open file 'opencv_core310d.lib'"とエラーが出る

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

OpenCV-3.1.0をVisual Studio2015で使いたいと思い、 
[初めてのOpenCV開発](http://www.buildinsider.net/small/opencv/004)
 ↑こちらのサイト様を見ながら環境構築をしていました。 
 上記サイト様の、2.1～2.5.3までを行い、coreとhighguiモジュールの設定がきちんと行われているか 
 確認するためにビルドを行うと、

```
cannnot open file 'opencv_core310d.lib'
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。

上記サイトの一番下にあるコードを試しました。

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>    // coreモジュールのヘッダーをインクルード
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp> // highguiモジュールのヘッダーをインクルード
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
// 1幅320px、高さ240pxで赤色の画像データを生成
cv::Mat redImg(cv::Size(320, 240), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));

// 2画像表示用のウィンドウを生成
cv::namedWindow("red", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

// 3ウィンドウに画像を表示
cv::imshow("red", redImg);

// 4キー入力を待機
cv::waitKey(0);

// 5作成したウィンドウを全て破棄
cv::destroyAllWindows();

return 0; }
```

［構成プロパティ］－［リンカー］－［入力］－［追加の依存ファイル］に'opencv_core310d.lib'が追加されていることの確認はしましたが、 
他に何か確認すべき点があれば教えていただきたいです。

windows10/64bit/OpenCV-3.1.0/Visual Studio2015/C++

Comment: OpenCVライブラリ自体のインストールはどのような手順で行ったのでしょうか？OpenCV 3.0以降はデフォルトで[opencv_core*.lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867289/)を生成しません。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/38613　マルチポスト

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> opencv_core310d.lib　が、libディレクトリ内に存在していませんでした。opencv_core310.libは存在するのですが、なぜでしょうか‌​

インストールしたOpenCVはどちらから入手しどのようにインストールしたものでしょうか？
http://opencv.org/downloads.html にある 2015-12-21 VERSION 3.1 OpenCV for Windows をインストールしてみましたが、`opencv_core310d.lib`だけでなく`opencv_core310.lib`も存在せず`opencv_world310.lib`と`opencv_world310d.lib`の２つに統合されていました。
再度環境を確認してください。

これらしかインストールされていないようでしたら、当然ではありますがこれらを追加ライブラリに指定することになり、参照されているWebサイトの記述は当てにならなさそうです。

Comment: opencv_core310d.lib　が、libディレクトリ内に存在していませんでした。opencv_core310.libは存在するのですが、なぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

［構成プロパティ］－［リンカー］－［入力］－［追加の依存ファイル］には　フルディレクトリを書いてみます、それとも、「VC++ライブラリディレクトリ」には、ディレクトリを書いてみてください。